# outsource inside-lyrics markup as custom command

Tags: lilypond

I have some music with lyrics. Inside the lyrics is a markup:

```
\relative { e'4 e d f g a }  
\addlyrics {
  ha -- cky me -- lis -- ma

  \once \override LyricText.extra-offset = #'(-0.11 . 0)
  \markup {
    \path #0.08 
      #'((moveto    0.000   0.040)
         (lineto    3.500   0.040))
  }
}
```

Since I use that specific markup in many places (always inside lyrics), I want to call it by a name. Like this:

```
\relative { e'4 e d f g a }  
\addlyrics {
  ha -- cky me -- lis -- ma
  \hackyMelisma
}
```

How do I need to define `hackyMelisma` in order to achieve this?

---

I tried

```
#(define-markup-command (hackyMelisma layout props) ()
  (interpret-markup layout props
    #{
        \once \override LyricText.extra-offset = #'(-0.11 . 0)
        \markup {
          \path #0.08 
            #'((moveto    0.000   0.040)
               (lineto    0.500   0.040))
        }
    #}))
```

but when I use it inside lyrics via `\hackyMelisma` I get a compile error

> unknown escaped string: `\hackyMelisma'.

I also tried

```
hackyMelisma = \once \override LyricText.extra-offset = #'(-0.11 . 0)
  \markup {
    \path #0.08 
      #'((moveto    0.000   0.040)
         (lineto    3.500   0.040))
  }
```

which does compile, but does not put the line where it should be. It creates the line where the `hackyMelisma` is defined (i.e. outside the staff), not where I reference it by `\hackyMelisma`.